# Integrating $\frac{x^3}{(81-x^2)^2}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I've been trying to figure out this integral for an hour or so now, but keep failing.  I can't figure out where I go wrong:

$$I = \int \frac{x^3}{(81-x^2)^2} dx$$

Let $x = 9sin\theta \implies dx = 9 \cos \theta d \theta$

$$I =\int \frac{9^3 \sin^3 \theta}{9^4(1-\sin^2 \theta)^2} 9 \cos \theta d\theta$$

$$I = \int \tan^3 \theta d\theta$$

$$I = \int \tan \theta \sec^2 \theta d \theta - \int \tan \theta d\theta$$

$$I = \frac{1}{2}tan^2 \theta + \ln| \cos \theta | + C$$

Using $cos \theta = \frac{\sqrt{81-x^2}}{9}$, $\tan \theta = \frac{x}{\sqrt{81-x^2}}$

$$I = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{x^2}{81-x^2}) + \frac{1}{2} \ln |\frac{81-x^2}{81}|+C$$

Somewhere I went terribly wrong, but I just can't figure out where.  I've done this problem around 5 times now.

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong? I'm sure you can use partial fractions to check it. But this approach looks fine to me too.

Comment: The answer is $\frac{\ln (x^2-81)}{2} - \frac{81}{2x^2 -162} + C$ I can't think of a way to transform my answer into that answer

Comment: They are equivalent. $\frac{1}{2} \ln |\frac{81-x^2}{81}|$ can be transformed to $\frac{1}{2} \ln |81-x^2|-\frac{1}{2} \ln 81$. The answer ignored the absolute value, which is not precisely correct. Also the $\frac{x^2}{81-x^2}$ is equivalent to $-1-\frac{81}{x^2-81}$. Remember that all the constant terms can be combined into $C$.

Comment: Wolfram give the solution $\frac{1}{2}(ln(x^2-81)-\frac{81}{x^2-81})$

Comment: The partial fraction expansion is $\frac{1}{2(x+9)}-\frac{9}{4(x+9)^2}+\frac{1}{2(x-9)}+\frac{9}{4(x-9)^2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively write $81-x^2=y$

$$\dfrac{x^3}{(81-x^2)^2}=\dfrac{81-(81-x^2)}{(81-x^2)^2}\cdot x $$